# Magento2 Observer Calling Multiple Times

Tags: magento2

In magento2 i am using almost 20 modules of thirdparty. I have one observer for sales_order_save_after which is calling by different modules. But when i print the log or when i checked my database the same file is calling 5 times. In database as well it is inserting multiple records. How can i restrict the observer execution?

Comment: Did you check, how many times $order->save() call? Is it 1 $order->save() with 5 times observer calls?

Comment: in each observer , they are saving one or more parameters of that order.

Comment: Did you try using Register?

Comment: `In database as well it is inserting multiple records.`  on which table?

Comment: @Dinesh are you able to solve this to stop event call two times ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that on  `sales_order_save_after` you want  ***to insert a record at your database table and this insertion happens one time for each order***.

Magento `sales_order_save_after` happen multiple when ***any data insertion/update*** happens on **sales_order** table using `save()` function on order model.

> This even fire when anything update/insert happens on the sales
>   order.shipment, invoice, credit memo entity. So this **event  RUN 
>   multiple time and the observer run multiple time.**.

*If you want single time insertion on your table on event `sales_order_save_after`.
So, you need to do some change at logic at observer class.*

- First, add **new column**  `order_id` to that table. On insertion of
  first called on your Observer insert order id with a record.
- Second. before **insertion happens on that table from your observer,
  check same order id's record exist at that table. if exist then do not run insert operation**.

### The code may look like

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Magento\Observer;

class SaveOrderAfter  implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Vendorname\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MyEntity\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
      \Vendorname\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\MyEntity\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory      
   ) {

       $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        // check record exits on not
        if(!$order){
            return ;

        }

        $items = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        // filter can be  add base on your logic
        $items->addFieldToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('order_id',$order->getId());
        $items->setPageSize(1)->setCurpage(1);

        // getSize > 1 means you have record exit at your table.
        // you can NOT insertion operation
        if($items->getSize() > 1){
            return ;
        }
        // insertation code  add below


    }

}
```

Comment: can we prevent call event 2 times without make a custom module ?

Comment: Cannot possiable..

Comment: can we use plugin "after save" ?

Comment: Can you please look into this -
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319306/magento-2-which-plugin-can-use-for-after-invoice-or-shipment-from-admin