# Magento 2 which plugin can use for after invoice or shipment from admin

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, event-observer, plugin

I am using this
di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="admin_plugin_order_save_after" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin\AdminPluginOrderSaveAfter"/>
    </type> 
</config>
```

AdminPluginOrderSaveAfter.php

```
<?php 
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class AdminPluginOrderSaveAfter
{
    protected $objectManager;
    protected $orderRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->orderRepositoryInterface = $orderRepositoryInterface;
    }

    public function afterSave(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepo, $order)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/xuz.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info("------admin after save plugin start------");
        if($order->getStatus() == "complete")
        {
            $logger->info('----complete----');
            $order->setCustomAttributeFlag("1");
        }
        else
        {
            $logger->info("------else------");
            $order->setCustomAttributeFlag("0");
        }


        return $order;
    }
}
```

This only works when order is created, I need to update order after invoice and shipment is generated from admin.

I also use this event "sales_order_save_after" but it is calling 2 times.

Anyone know to update order after invoice and shipment is generated ?